# Decomposition into partial fractions : $(n^3-1)/(n^3+1)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-fractions

How can I decompose the polynomial fraction $(n^3-1)/(n^3+1)$? I already know that $a^3-b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$ and $a^3+b^3 = (a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$. Is it possible to decompose this into partial fractions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the  highest degree of the numerator & that of the denominator & their respective coefficients are same,

$$\dfrac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}=1+\dfrac A{n+1}+\dfrac{Bn+C}{n^2-n+1}$$